# Comment Form - E-mail Not Required!

Tags: comments, functions

I need to know how to make one of the fields on my comment not NOT required. How can I set the e-mail field in the comment field to not be required, but optional?

Answer (score 1):

`Settings` > `Discussion` > `Other comment settings` > uncheck `Comment author must fill out name and e-mail`

**Update**

Well, as far as WP is concerned these are glued together. You can add your own check for empty name, something like this (not tested):

```
add_filter('preprocess_comment', 'require_comment_author');

function require_comment_author($commentdata) {

    if ('' == $commentdata['comment_author'])
        wp_die('Error: please enter a valid name.');

    return $commentdata;
}
```

But then will also need to modify form generation so name is marked up as required and email not...

Comment: Yes, but then how would i require them to fill out that name then? I want to require the name and comment, but not the e-mail address.